# Interchanging roles of $A$ and $B$ in geometric Hahn-Banach

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

Consider the following version of the geometric Hahn-Banach theorem: let $X$ be a locally convex topological vector space over the real or the complex numbers, $A$ and $B$ two non-empty, disjoint and convex subsets of $X$ with $A$ compact and $B$ closed, then there is a continuous linear functional $f$ on $X$ such that $$ \sup_{x\in A} \Re f (x) < \inf_{x \in B} \Re f (x).$$

What if I want the reverse the inequality? Is it true that there is a continuous linear functional $g$ on $X$ such that
$$ \sup_{x\in B} \Re g (x) < \inf_{x \in A} \Re g (x)?$$

My naive idea is to take $g=-f$, but does this work and why?

Comment: Yes, it works. Have you any specific reason to be unsure about it?

Answer (score 0):

Just let $g = -f$. As $f$ is linear continuous, $g$ is also. As we have
\begin{align*}
  \Re g(x) &= \Re (-f)(x) \\
   &= - \Re f(x)\\
  \sup_{x\in B} \Re g(x) &= \sup_{x\in B} -\Re f(x)\\
      &= -\inf_{x\in B} \Re f(x) \\
      &< -\sup_{x\in A} \Re f(x) & \text{by the inequality for $f$}\\
      &= \inf_{x\in A} -\Re f(x)\\
      &= \inf_{x \in A} \Re g(x)
\end{align*}